# CSS code to align to left buttons

Tags: css, wordpress

Can someone help me with this one:

I would like to align to left the buttons on my wordpress webpage:
[Wordpress webpage with the buttons](http://www.virtual-forms.com/forums)

Here is the screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeveb.png)

Comment: There might be several things in you enclosing html and css, which are making buttons away from left border. Could you provide the piece of markup so that exact solution can be suggested ?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the "how to ask" docs, especially how to [include an MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your question will get closed / downvoted because as it is now, there's three major issues: 1. You are linking to a site, that *will change*, and when it does, this question no longer has value to future visitors.  2. You aren't including the relevant HTML / CSS to recreate the issue you're facing. 3. Your "problem statement" is a bit vague, and could be sharpened.